# "Translate" Framework version from output

Tags: c#, .net

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) Windows shows how to find the framework version.

Suppose I only need to know the current version, what it is? I mean the output of the example that given by Windows gives:

```
v2.0.50727  2.0.50727.4016  SP2
v3.0  3.0.30729.4037  SP2
v3.5  3.5.30729.01  SP1
v4
  Client  4.0.30319
  Full  4.0.30319
```

I don't need all the SP stuff, I only the the framework version for example:

`4.6.2`

How to "translate" the output?

Comment: Why don't you follow the article and look for the Registry value? Also, what's the reason behind this?

Comment: What do you mean "current version"? Do you want to know what version your program is running on? Or the highest installed version?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The reason is that my app require some .NET Frameworks

Comment: @RonBeyer The highest installed version

Comment: As soon as you open your application, Windows will ask you to install the target .NET framework if not installed already

Comment: I need to do it programmatic @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: If your application needs, for example, .NET 4.6.1 to run, you cannot do it programmatically for the simple fact that you cannot run the application

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's more complex.. i need to check it  programmatic

Comment: How could it possibly be more complex? **Windows does that for you, you don't have to do anything**

Comment: My app runs on Windows Server and checks if: .NET framework 3.5 installed if so it does some stuff. if .NET 6.7 do other stuff etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code that you have given through the link. I am getting the versions through list and printing it in the main method. Please try this code

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> version = GetVersionFromRegistry();

        Console.WriteLine(".Net Versions");

        foreach (var item in version)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<string> GetVersionFromRegistry()
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        // Opens the registry key for the .NET Framework entry.
        using (RegistryKey ndpKey =
            RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "").
            OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\"))
        {
            // As an alternative, if you know the computers you will query are running .NET Framework 4.5 
            // or later, you can use:
            // using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
            // RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\"))
            foreach (string versionKeyName in ndpKey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                if (versionKeyName.StartsWith("v"))
                {

                    RegistryKey versionKey = ndpKey.OpenSubKey(versionKeyName);
                    string name = (string)versionKey.GetValue("Version", "");
                    string sp = versionKey.GetValue("SP", "").ToString();
                    string install = versionKey.GetValue("Install", "").ToString();
                    if (install != "") //no install info, must be later.
                    {
                        if (sp != "" && install == "1")
                        {
                            output.Add(name);
                        }

                    }
                    if (name != "")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    foreach (string subKeyName in versionKey.GetSubKeyNames())
                    {
                        RegistryKey subKey = versionKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName);
                        name = (string)subKey.GetValue("Version", "");
                        if (name != "")
                            sp = subKey.GetValue("SP", "").ToString();
                        install = subKey.GetValue("Install", "").ToString();
                        if (install == "") //no install info, must be later.
                            output.Add(name);
                        else
                        {
                            if (sp != "" && install == "1")
                            {
                                output.Add(name);
                            }
                            else if (install == "1")
                            {
                                output.Add(name);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives three versions

Comment: Actually you have three versions in your computer.Take the maximum value after sorting the list if you need the latest one